# Not Found - React application deployment to Heroku issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, heroku

I have a TypeScript React app in frontend folder with the build folder ready after running `npm run build` inside the frontend folder, and a backend folder that has `server.js` that has the following code

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();

const __dirname = path.resolve();
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/build')));
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

In the root folder that contains the frontend and backend folders I have `.env` file that has `NODE_ENV = production` and `Procfile` that has `web: node backend/server.js`. Also, in the root folder, I have `package.json` file that has the script `"start": "node backend/server"`

With all of this, I follow the following steps on my terminal to deploy my application to heroku

- Login to heroku using `heroku login`
- Create a new application on heroku using `heroku create my-app`. At this point I enter the `NODE_ENV` env variable on heroku and set it to `production`
- Enter `heroku git:remote -a my-pp`
- And finally `git push heroku master`

The deployment process shows no errors, but when I open my app, it shows `Not Found` on the page.

I have been trying for 3 days to deploy my app with no success. I appreciate any help in deploying the app to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following through this documentation about nodejs deployment on heroku.:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

What does `heroku local web` says?

This could be also useful:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#set-up

Try `web: npm start` in your Procfile. And add the script to package.json accordingly.

I think you might have to specify a build script which builds your frontend and creates the index.html in your `/frontend/build` folder.
In this case you would add `web: npm build` in your Procfile.

Comment: I tried to use `"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend"` script to build the app on deployment, but got the error that it cannot find `/temp/xxx/frontend/package.json`

Comment: Where is your package.json?

Comment: I fixed the problem by deleting the .git file and initializing it again. I found others reported the same problem, and this was the solution